# koa-body file upload async

Tags: javascript, koa

I'm having some issues with cut off files.  Can someone please confirm, is this going to complete the upload before returning my response? What can be done to fix it?

```js
const router = require('koa-router')(),
    koaBody = require('koa-body')({
        multipart: true,
        formLimit: 2000 * 1024,
        formidable: {
            uploadDir,
        },
    })

router.post('/uploadImage', koaBody, function *() {
    const {fields, files} = this.request.body
    const f = files['files[]']
    const {username} = fields

    // console.log('uploadImage', username, f.path, f.name)

    if(res.status !== 200) {
        this.status = res.status
        this.statusText = res.statusText
        return
    }
    const {ipfspath} = yield res.json()
    const url = 'https://example.com' + ipfspath
    this.body = {files: [{url}]}
})
export default router.routes()
```

Comment: It looks like koa-body does wait for the end event from formidable: https://github.com/dlau/koa-body/blob/5cbd494434dd82ac8b5b3d300717753a456ceb8c/index.js#L58

Comment: It's waiting on it. Look at the 'end' event in the 'formy' function lower down in the file. I can't recreate your issue locally, the entire file gets dropped in uploadsDir and the route always waits. Can't see an issue with your snippet. Maybe there's an idiosyncrasy in the babel-compiled code? (I don't use it)